# Android OnItemClick listener Not Working in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, onclick

I am developing an application with list-view, which consists of check box as well as Rating bar, here my problem is while i am clicking on arrow button or on listview on item click listener is not working for me?
any one can help me i am trying for longtime........

[image]

```
ListView lv = getListView(); 
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{ 
 @Override 
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3) 
  { 
  Toast.makeText(SuggestionActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
  } 
  }); 
  }
```

Comment: Would help if we had some code to look at.

Comment: ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3) {
      Toast.makeText(SuggestionActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
     }
    });
   }

Comment: this is the code which i have used.. i have extended list activity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635891/onitemclicklistner-is-not-working-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645880/list-view-with-on-item-click-listener-android ... there are answers ... YOU HAVE FOCUSABLE ELEMENT IN LISTVIEW ROW (Button, Rating Bar, Checkbox)

Comment: try to set click able property as lv.setClickable(true) before  setonclicklistener.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
ListView lv = getListView();

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) {

   });
}
```

Comment: i have used it.. and i am having check boxes as well as rating bar?

Comment: check it properly, in activity also,add  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4163/discussion-between-polamreddy-and-gujjula-nikhilreddy)

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your layout items. Try to disable the clickability of them using these:

```
 android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```